# C# Sockets communication between two computers

Tags: c#, sockets, ip, client-server, message

i want to let 2 c# apps each one is on a separate computer and both connected to the same ADSL router to send messages to each other i know that we have to use Sockets and tried many solutions on the internet but they are all working at the same computer but not working on a separate computers.
i believe that the problem is in the ip addresses but i tried a lot with no good results
is there any simple code to help please

i tried this function on server side

```
    public static void StartServer()
    {

        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("DESKTOP-SBJHC7I");
        IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress.ToString());
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);


        try
        {

            // Create a Socket that will use Tcp protocol      
            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            // A Socket must be associated with an endpoint using the Bind method  
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);

            // Specify how many requests a Socket can listen before it gives Server busy response.  
            // We will listen 10 requests at a time  
            listener.Listen(10);

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();

            // Incoming data from the client.    
            string data = null;
            byte[] bytes = null;

            while (true)
            {
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            handler.Send(msg);
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

and this function in the client side

```
    public static void StartClient()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        try
        {
            // Connect to a Remote server  
            // Get Host IP Address that is used to establish a connection  
            // In this case, we get one IP address of localhost that is IP : 127.0.0.1  
            // If a host has multiple addresses, you will get a list of addresses  
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("DESKTOP-SBJHC7I");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.    
            Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.    
            try
            {
                // Connect to Remote EndPoint  
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.    
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

                // Send the data through the socket.    
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                // Receive the response from the remote device.    
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Echoed test = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                // Release the socket.    
                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you have configured the firewalls and checked its not the issue?

Comment: when the app started the system asked me if i wanted to allow this app to accesses the network or not and i let it allow

Comment: Check is IPHostEntry host - correct IP address of your server and (for test) disable FireWall on server site.

Answer (score 1):

please make sure that your client is connected to the same IP on which server is started. because it seems in your code that your client connecting to host which you getting it from localhost identity. For your testing purpose please hardcode the Server's IP address in your Remoteendpoint. if still the issue same then I will share code to test on a different networks.